# <InsertAfter> & <InsertBefore> Tags are not working with Custom tabs in Office-JS

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, cpu-word

My question is regarding the CustomTabs option in the Office JS Manifest file.
I created a custom tab element in my Office JS manifest file.

It's working fine and appears as the last item from the right. But I would like this custom tab to place after Home Tab and according to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/customtab the  or  should do the trick.
But's it's not working in my case. I tried running the code on MAC and as-well-as on windows and the issue remains the same.

I tried searching the internet but couldn't find anything related to it.

Any pointer or help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Aman

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>05c2e1c9-3e1d-406e-9a91-e9ac64854151</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Task Pane Add-in"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!-- <OfficeTab id="TabHome"> -->
              <CustomTab id="TabCustom1">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>

              <Label resid="customTabLabel1"/>
              <InsertAfter>TabHome</InsertAfter>
               </CustomTab>
            <!-- </OfficeTab> --> 
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel1" DefaultValue="ABC" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Note, the `InsertAfter` element is not available in Outlook. Could you specify the exact version of the host application? Is it Word?

Comment: Hello @EugeneAstafiev, thanks for the reply. I am not using it on Outlook, I am using it in Word. In Windows the version of word is `Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14228.20216) 64-bit ` and on Mac it's `Version 16.52 (21080801)`. Thanjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately InsertBefore and InsertAfter elements are currently only supported on PowerPoint. Expanding this to Excel and Word is in our roadmap but we currently have no ETA. Will work with the content team on updating the documentation to reflect this limitation, sorry for the confusion.